# Apply a function to a column and keeping all columns in the result

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table with three columns and i want to normalize just one column.

Doing this:

`snapshots[,lapply(.SD, normalize),.SDcols= !c("id", "label")]`

The result will only have one column. How can I keep `id` and `label` columns?

Comment: `snapshots[,yourNormCol :=normalize(yourNormCol)]` untestet because you dont give any data.

Comment: also you could: `snapshots$yourNormCol <- normalize(yourNormCol)`

Comment: Thanks @AndreElrico. How can i extend that solution to more than one column?

Comment: I believe you could use `snapshots[,.(lapply(.SD, normalize),id,label),.SDcols= !c("id", "label")]` when you have more cols to normalize. #untested again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In data.table, a common practice is to use `.SD` when you have to apply a function to more than one column. In case of just one column, you can directly do (also suggested in comments by @Andre):

```
snapshots[, column_name := normalize(column_name)]
```

This way you can keep all the existing columns while modifying one column.

Comment: But i did give reference to your comment. Also, neither is this answer any exclusive.

Comment: You're being too cheap to get some rep ;-) , that's what I'm saying.

Comment: I answer when I feel I can add something more than in comments. Your answer in comments isn't something which is hard to figure out. I thought, its important here to explain why not .SD makes sense while modifying one column and that's why I posted it here. I am not here after reps but to learn and share my knowledge.

Comment: I guess the one or two sentences would have fitted well into the comment section. Anyways have a nice day :-).